# continuous music player Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, frame, audio-player, soundmanager2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninterrupted background music on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529952/uninterrupted-background-music-on-website)

I have a music player built using SoundManager2 and need a way to add it to my wordpress site so that it continues playing if the user changes the page they are on.

Are frames the best way to do this? I cant hurt SEO at all!!

Thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: Can you give us a link to the site! I'll love to visit a site with playing background music! ohhh and it doesn't stop when you change page! fabulous!

Comment: It is a duplicate, but the accepted answer there does not answer the question.

Comment: @lanzz If you rule out frames and popups, there might not be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to Ajaxify your website I think, using frames or popups are not a very nice way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your website into a dynamic website using ajax/jquery.

This way part of your page can load and play the audio/video, while the rest of the page is simply updated as the user browses around the site without interrupting the media.